# adding a song to a playlist with a sequence number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to add a song to my table called PlaylistSong where I have my songs in the different playlists from my Playlist table.
I want to write a query where I type the songID of the song to add to a playlist(PlaylistID).

That is simple, but the problem is, that I need to make the SeqNo automatic somehow.

(Something like this?)

INSERT INTO PlayListSong (PlayListID, SongID, SeqNo) values (1, 2, ?)

Here is the table:

```
╔═════════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ PlaylistID  ║ SongID ║  SeqNo ║
╠═════════════╬════════╬════════╣
║           1 ║      2 ║      1 ║
║           1 ║      3 ║      2 ║
║           2 ║      4 ║      1 ║
║           2 ║      5 ║      2 ║
╚═════════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: Max(SeqNo)+1 wouldn't solve your problem?
By the way, Why can't that be a running number in your select query, instead of storing them in the database?

Comment: Is SeqNo an `identity` column? Have you looked at using a `sequence` object for the a default value if not?

Comment: @MrGenius this is for an assigment, so unfortunately I can not change that. As for your suggestion, do I insert that in place of the question mark? I tried that, and it tells me that SeqNo is an invalid column.

Comment: @alroc SeqNo is not an identity column. That wouldn't allow me to have same numbers more than once right? Which would defeat the purpose.

Comment: You didn't clearly specify the requirements for the field.

Comment: I'm sorry, thought that was made clear in the example. The column is for showing what number a song is on a playlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
INSERT INTO PlayListSong  (PlayListID, SongID, SeqNo) values (1, 2, (SELECT ISNULL(Max(SeqNo),0)+1 FROM [dbo].PlayListSong 
WHERE PlayListID=1 ) )
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The max SeqNo doesn't differentiate between the PlayListID. This would cause the SeqNo on one of the Playlists to skip numbers, if you get what I mean.

Comment: My bad, I completely forgot to change the value of the PlayListID when testing. Your solution works!